# how to output variable to a file?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I've got a `Get metadata` activity that goes to an sftp server and lists the files:

[image]

**Is it possible to output this list to a file without using a function??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a particular reason you have to log the output to a file? If you just call a Get Metadata task in Azure Data Factory it will be logged as part of the pipeline run and default logging anyway.  You can then access those logs if required.

Alternately, a common pattern I use with *Get Metadata* task is a *For Each* loop and then host multiple tasks within the *For Each*, eg a Copy task to move the files from SFTP to wherever you want, and a Stored Proc task for custom logging to a database.  Pass the filename from the *Get Metadata* task to the *Stored Proc* task as a parameter.  Something like this:

[image: ADF pattern]

Comment: Where does it get logged?

Comment: If you're running in Debug mode they are listed in the Output section (the little doors with the arrows).  If you've run via a schedule or event trigger then have a look at the Azure portal or Powershell cmdlets eg (`Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2PipelineRun`).

Comment: could we get the logs via REST? is there a REST version of `Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2PipelineRun` ?

Answer (score -1):

> Is it possible to output this list to a file?

Yes, you could connect an Azure Function Activity with Get Metadata Activity.Just pass the file list as parameter into Azure Function: `@activity('Get Metadata1').output`

[image]

Then save the data as your need inside function.(Such as call the blob storage sdk to save the data into blob storage) Surely,`Web Activity` is another option to call your custom api to save the data.