# is it possible to copy only the first few bytes of a file?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a copy activity where the source is sftp and the sink is blob storage.

**Is it possible to ONLY copy the first few hundred bytes of a file?**

Answer (score -1):

I see the answer for your another SO thread [how to output variable to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59470838/how-to-output-variable-to-a-file), its solution is also suitable for the current scenario to return the first few hundred bytes of a file in Azure Functions to Copy Activity.

If you don't want to use this way, I think the only solution is to follow the offical document [`Use custom activities in an Azure Data Factory pipeline`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-dotnet-custom-activity) to create a custom activity in programming to realize the feature you want.